# App to peek at 2nd monitor?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

I have two screens. The 2nd is not facing me. I occasionally want to check if it looks correct. How do I get my screen (monitor 1) to show me what monitor 2 looks like briefly? This should not make monitor 2 show the contents of monitor 1.

Comment: What are you displaying on your 2nd monitor? If it's a full-screen window, you could use Aero taskbar thumbnails to see what the window looks like.

Comment: @ChrisN: At the moment, just a browser. But i'd like to see if say notepad was on top of it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use to snipping tool included in Windows 7 to generate a full screen screen-shot of your entire desktop. This should allow you to see what your desktop on the other monitor currently looks like.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have to select the entire 2nd screen blindly which is ok but it also puts the image there so i still see nothing and now have a still image in the way

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on a Windows 7 machine at the moment so I couldn't full test it. Are you using the "Full-screen Snip" or the "Free-form snip" option (You should be able to select it from the drop down arrow next to "New". The "Full-screen" option should mean you don't need to blindly select and the preview should show on your main monitor.